# Jackson: JsonMappingException deserializing Arrays of JSON objects

Tags: java, json, web-services, jersey, jackson

I have a Jersey webservice producing the following JSON:

```
{"ConfigData":[{"@name":"Admin Component Version","@value":"version 1","@type":"String"},{"@name":"Component Version","@value":"version 1","@type":"String"}]}
```

From this JAX-B object:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ConfigData")
public class ConfigData {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "name", required = true)
    String name;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "value", required = true)
    String value;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "type", required = true)
    String type;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "groupId", required = false)
    String groupId;
    [...]
}
```

I am running a Unit tests with the following:

```
    final WebResource webResource = resource();
    final ClientResponse response = webResource.path(
            VersionProviderTest.SERVICE_PATH).get(ClientResponse.class);
    String jsonResponse = response.getEntity(String.class);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    //Exception is thrown at the line below obviously
    ConfigData[] list = mapper.readValue(jsonResponse.getBytes(),ConfigData[].class);
```

Why is this exception thrown? What am I missing? This is my first attempt at using Jackson like this to Marshall and UnMarchall classes. It seems like everything is there...

Thanks,

Comment: because this is not an array, this is an object with one field `ConfigData`, and value of this field is an array

Comment: This is why it does not start with a [ I assume. Then how should I go about unmarshalling this JSON output?

Comment: Create a wrapper class that has an array field of type `ConfigData` and use that for your `readValue()`.

Comment: unwrap root object using `objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);`

Comment: @hoaz Looking at http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.8.8/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/SerializationConfig.Feature.html I cannot find the UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE ... could you provide more information?

Comment: it is introduced after 1.9: http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/DeserializationConfig.Feature.html#UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well why not skip Jackson entirely and grab the output directly from jersey. They apparently are not using the same Json format by default.

```
    final WebResource webResource = resource();
    final ClientResponse response = webResource.path(
            VersionProviderTest.SERVICE_PATH).get(ClientResponse.class);
    ConfigData[] list = response.getEntity(ConfigData[].class);
```

This works like a charm!